# Slightly different meanings of "National" and usage

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary, programming

I'm a programmer and I have to name some columns in a database. It's about sports competitions. I have to classify the leagues and competitions in two properties. One of them is if they are national games, such as World Cup, but not Champions League. The other one is, if they're national leagues such as Barclay's Premier League, not Europa League.

Both "national" and "international" sounds to describe both. I don't want to use the word "local" for a league like "Barclay's Premier League", as "local" describes a league which is played in a city or town. I may use "domestic" but still, "national" would sound like a domestic league either.

My question is, what are the two words that I can use, which would not be confusing and make you would understand what it describes even though you don't know the other one, and which has opposites.

Comment: Domestic sounds fine for a league within a specific country, and International for Champions League etc. However your data model doesn't sound quite right. I think you need an additional field indicating whether a league is for clubs or countries.

Comment: I exactly looking for a word to differenciate that =) I'm already using two columns and looking for a word the tell the difference between club leagues and country leagues. We call World Cup as an "International" tournament, because it's between "Nations". And we call Champion's League "International", because it's not domestic. The meaning of those two "International"s are different from each other.

Comment: Well just call it ClubOrCountry and make it boolean.

Comment: No, ClubOrCountry = true means it's fro clubs or countries, not useful. Call it Club or call it Country and make it boolean (if there are never any other choices - otherwise, create an enum or seperate table so after "club" and "country" you can add "celebrity teams" or "company teams").
I apologize for the IT bit, just realized i'm on ELU :P

Answer (score 1):

Your question was slightly confusing as you ask for two words but there seems to be 3 categories.

For this I would use

For local leagues e.g. Premier league

> Domestic

For World Cup etc.

> International

For Europa League etc.

> Continental

Alternatively, if you want to group domestic leagues and european leagues you could use the terms club and country to describe the difference.

Based on your comment id suggest either:

1) 3 categories

- Club Domestic
- Club International
- International

2) 2 categories plus a flag indicating club or country

- Domestic
- International

Comment: But European Basketball Championship is a "continental" championship and Fifa Club World Championship is an "international" championship in this type of definition. However I want World Cup and European Basketball Championship or Fifa Club World Championship and Europa League to be in the same category. What I mean is, in the "Domestic vs something" difference, clubs are playing agains clubs in clubs from the same country or clubs from other countries, and in the "National vs something" difference, the teams are national teams.

Comment: Updated my Answer with some other suggestions

Comment: Thank you. I think the first one would work good, as actually there are only three options, not four.